# Latent Trait Models in R

Tags: r, mixed-models

Does anyone have experience with obtaining latent trait scores from a repeated measure design. Currently, my data is in long format (where baseline data is stacked on post-treatment data, similar to the way you would fix the dataset for lmer). With this dataset in long format, I attempted to use the mixedmirt function from the mirt package and regressed the latent trait on Time; however, I am unsure if mirt recognized that my design is repeated. It seemed to model the correlation and covariance in the latent abilities. Does anyone have experience with mirt or can recommend another R package for my analysis?

Comment: might be more appropriately adressed [at stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). As a quick hint, in latent trait models multiple measurements are typically modeled as multiple latent dimensions with common item properties rather than with latent regression.